# Vector space model cosine tf-idf for finding similar documents

Tags: text-mining, similarity

Have corpus of over million documents

For a given document want to find similar documents using cosine as in [vector space model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space_model)

$d_1 \cdot d_2 / ( ||d_1|| ||d_2|| )$

All tf have been normalized using augmented frequency, to prevent a bias towards longer documents as in this [tf-idf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf):

$tf(t,d)=0.5+0.5\frac{f(t,d)}{\mathrm{max}\{f(t,d): t\in d\}}$

Have pre-calculated all $||d||$
Have the values for the denominator pre-calculated
So for a given $d1$ need to score over 1 million $d2$
Have a threshold of 0.6 cosine for similarity

I can observe that for a given $||d_1||$ there is a fairly narrow range of $||d_2||$ for cosine $\ge$ 0.6
For example in one search for similar for a cosine of $\ge$ 0.6 and a $||d_1||$ of 7.7631 then $||d_2||$ range from 7.0867 to 8.8339
Where outside the threshold of cosine 0.6 $||d_2||$ range from to 0.7223 to 89.3395
This was with standard tf document normalization
It is looking at a LOT of $||d_2||$ that don't have a chance of being a cosine 0.6 match

Finally the question:
For a give $||d_1||$ and cosine of >= 0.6 how can determine the range of $||d_2||$ that have a chance?
Which $||d_2||$ can I safely eliminate?

I also know the number of terms in $d_1$ and $d_2$ if there is term count range.

Via experimentation
$||d2|| > .8 ||d1||$ and $||d2|| < ||d1|| / .8 $
seems to be safe but hopefully there is range that is proven to be safe

Created some test cases with a very some unique terms, some not so unique, and some common.  Sure enough you can take the most unique term and increase that frequency in the compare.  The numerator will (dot product) go up and so will ||compare|| and will get a cosine very close to 1.

Kind of related and NOT the question.
I am also using the tf-idf to group documents into groups. 
The customer base I am selling into are used to near near dup groups. 
There I am taking a related approach in I look as the smallest term count and evaluate it against term count up to 3x.  So a term count of 10 looks at 10  thru 30 (4-9 already had their shot at 10).  Here I can afford to miss one have it picked up in another.  I am 10% done and the biggest ratio is 1.8.

Please identify the flaws in this analysis
**As pointed out by AN6U5 there is a flaw in this analysis**
It is no longer a cosine if the document is normalized on weighted
**And as pointed out by Mathew also cannot conclude  d1⋅d2≤d1⋅d1**
I am still hoping for something to give me a hard bound but people that seems to know this stuff are telling me no
I don't want to change the question so just ignore this
I will do some analysis and maybe post a separate question on document normalization
For the purpose of this question assume the document is normalized on raw tf
Sorry but I am just not good with what ever markup is used to make the   equations
So in my notation
||d1|| = sqrt(sum(w1 x w1))
d1 dot d2 = sum(w1 X w2)
Assume d1 is the shorter document
The very best d1 dot d2 that can be achieved is d1 dot d1
If d1 is marry 100 paul 20
And d2 is marry 100 paul 20 peter 1
Normalized
d1 is marry 1 paul 1/5
d2 is marry 1 paul 1/5  peter 1/100
Clearly marry and paul have the same idf in both documents
The best possible d1 dot d2 is d1 dot d1
The maximum possible match to d1 is d1
cos = d1 dot d1 / ||d1|| ||d2||
square both sides
cos X cos = (d1 dot d1) X (d1 dot d1) / ( (d1 dot d1) X (d2 dot d2) ) 
cos X cos = (d1 dot d1) / (d2 dot d2)
take the square root of both side
cos = ||d1|| / ||d2||
is ||d2|| not bounded by the cos?
If I just use ||d2|| >= cos ||d1|| and ||d2|| <= ||d1|| / cos I get the computational speed I need

Comment: Your argument that concludes with a bound determined by  $\mathrm{cos}=\frac{||d_1||}{||d_2||}$ doesn't work because "The very best d1 dot d2 that can be achieved is d1 dot d1" is incorrect. While $\frac{d_1\cdot d_2}{||d_1||\ ||d_2||}\le\frac{d_1\cdot d_1}{||d_1||\ ||d_1||}$, it is not the case that $d_1\cdot d_2\le d_1\cdot d_1$. For this particular class of vectors, it may work in enough cases that it's a decent approximation, but it'd be considerably harder to establish that it's always the case.

Comment: @MatthewGraves I think I agree with you.  Not my expertise but I am still hacking away at it.

Answer (score 4):

**Unfortunately, the math simplifies to show that you can't rigorously justify restricting the cosine similarity comparison of the vectors based on their lengths.**

The key point is that the cosine similarity metric normalizes based on length, so that only the unit vectors are considered.  I know this isn't necessarily the answer that you wanted, but the math clearly shows that the cosine similarity metrics is agnostic to vector length.

**Lets look at the math in more detail:**

You are applying a cosine similarity metric and requiring that that metric be larger than 0.6:

$$similarity=\cos{(\theta)}=\frac{\mathbf{A}\cdot\mathbf{B}}{||A|| ||B||}\geq0.6$$.

But the scalar lengths on the bottom can be distributed into the cross products above (distributive property):

$$\frac{\mathbf{A}\cdot\mathbf{B}}{||A|| ||B||} = \frac{\mathbf{A}}{||A||}\cdot\frac{\mathbf{B}}{||B||}=\hat{\mathbf{A}}\cdot\hat{\mathbf{B}}$$.

Now $\hat{\mathbf{A}}$ and $\hat{\mathbf{B}}$ are vectors that point in the same direction as $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ but they have been normalized to length one.  So the definition of the cosine similarity metric is the take the original vectors, normalize them to length one, and then measure the dot product of the unit vectors.

Therefor:

$$similarity=\cos{(\theta)}=\frac{\mathbf{d1}\cdot\mathbf{d2}}{||d1|| ||d2||}=\hat{\mathbf{d1}}\cdot\hat{\mathbf{d2}}\geq0.6$$

depends only on the orientation of the vectors and not on their magnitude (i.e. length).

**Reconciling this with what you are doing:**

Despite what the results of the linear algebra show, you might still be seeing a statistically significant result.  Practically speaking you may be finding that the statistics show that length restrictions are valid for your data.  For instance, you might be finding that tweets never share a cosine similarity $\geq0.6$ when compared with Tolstoy's "War and Peace".  If your statistics look good for using $||d2|| > .8 ||d1||$ and $||d2|| < ||d1|| / .8$ then I suggest you go with it as these type of canopy restrictions are very useful in saving computing time.

You can perhaps reconcile what you have been doing with distance metrics by also considering the Euclidean distance.  Where as the cosine similarity only returns a value between -1 and 1 based on the angle between the two vectors, the Euclidean distances will return values that depend on the lengths of the two vectors.  In some sense, you are combining aspects of the Euclidean distance with cosine similarity.

It makes fairly good sense to require that the relative lengths be within 25% of one another in the sense that this combines an aspect of Euclidean distance to create group-by canopies, which cuts computation time, then length agnostic cosine similarity can be used as the final determinant.

Note that 1/.8 =1.25, so d2>=.8d1 is a tighter restriction than d2<=d1/.8.  I suggest using d2>=.75d1 and d2<=1.25d1 as this is symmetric.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think this isn't making use of the fact that vector lengths come mostly from the shared idf weights, because of the tf normalization scheme he's using. If a document has a very low norm, that implies that it does not contain rare words (or contains them at a very low fractional frequency), which means that it can be ruled out as similar to a document that only contains rare words.

But how tight this constraint is in general seems unclear to me. It's probably the case that theoretical bounds are very wide compared to observed empirical bounds.

Comment: @Matthew Graves, All I'm saying is that cosine similarity is agnostic to vector length.  He is asking how differences in vector length can affect the resulting cosine similarity and the answer is: they can't.

Comment: The empirical correlation cannot be ignored.  There has be a way to correlate the randomness of the corpus to abound if only statistical.  I don't have enough rep on this site for an up vote to register.

Comment: Here is where I don't agree.  It does not normalize based on length.  It normalizes on the single most common term.    A longer document can only dilute.  I am willing to adjust how normalization is performed to get a bound I can support.

Comment: Thanks for modifying your question. It better clarifies what you are trying to accomplish.  Note that your modified normalization makes this actually **not** a cosine similarity, since this is strictly defined.  I would suggest a few additional edits to spell this out.  Take care and good luck.

Comment: Excellent point, thank you.  Since this is not my expertise I am going to stick with standard tf normalization until I have a solid reason not to.

Answer (score 3):

First, let's try to get some intuition why this would work. $||d_i||$ seems to serve as a word rarity measure, which seems plausible as something to filter on. If documents use dissimilar numbers of rare words, it'll be difficult for them to line up on the cosine similarity measure. But it seems unlikely to me that this cutoff will *only* depend on $||d_i||$, rather than also on the structure in the tf or idf weights that go into $||d_i||$.

To work through some algebra, let me introduce a few more terms (and rename some to shorter ones):

Let $d_1$ be a vector of tf weights $[t_1, t_2, ...]$ element-wise multiplied by a vector of idf weights $[w_1, w_2, ...]$ to get the final weights $[d_1, d_2, ...]$. We know that $0.5\le t_i\le 1$ and $0\le w_i\le 6$ (because of the corpus size and assuming we're using base 10, it doesn't matter if we're not). Let $D_1=||d_1||$.

Knowing $d_1$, we want to construct a delta vector $x$, such that $d_1+x$ has the minimal (or maximal) $X$ subject to the constraints that:

$X=\sqrt{\sum_i w_i^2 (t_i+x_i)^2}$

$0.6D_1X\le \sum_i w_i^2t_i(t_i+x_i)$ (1)

$0.5\le t_i+x_i \le 1$

Because we didn't use the raw tf weight for $x$, $x_i=0\ \forall i$ is in the solution space. I'm also ignoring the more complicated constraint that at least one $d_i+x_i=1$, because we can't express that linearly. We'll leave it as is and hope that the optimizer ends up setting one of them to 1.

Intuitively, it seems like the set of possible $x$ should be convex, but even if so we're already in the realm of [quadratically constrained programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratically_constrained_quadratic_program). Note that we can solve for minimal $X^2$ instead of minimal $X$, because $X>0$, but we probably can't use this methodology to maximize $X$ (i.e. minimize $-X$). But thankfully this'll be easily solvable if $P$ is [positive semidefinite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix). So what is $P$? We need to rewrite (1) in the correct form, which starts by squaring both sides:

$0\ge 0.36D_1^2\sum_i w_i^2 (t_i+x_i)^2-\sum_{i,j}w_i^4t_it_j(t_i+x_i)(t_j+x_j)$

We can rewrite this as $0\ge x^TPx+q^Tx+r$ where $P_{i,j}=0.36D_1^2-w_i^2t_it_j$ if $i=j$ and $-w_i^2t_it_j$ otherwise.

It's non-obvious to me that $P$ has to be positive semidefinite, but that'll be easy to check for any individual $d_1$. If so, pop this into a QP solver and you'll get a lower bound on $X$. If not, we're in trouble.

Can we also get a practical upper bound? I'm not sure. Obviously there's some finite upper bound, since we can calculate the maximum possible $X$ from the idf vector $w$ easily. But the fact that the minimum tf weight is 0.5 instead of 0 is throwing off my intuitions about how to create an adversarial $x$ with maximum $X$, and so the best approach that I'm coming up with is gradient descent, which may or may not find the actual global maximum but will probably be close.

Comment: I don't agree with ||d|| with seems to serve as a rarity measure.  It is normalized.    "Mary had a little lamb" will have a smaller || than "Marry had a white little lamb".   And "oddxxA oddxxB oddxxC" will have a smaller || than "oddxxA oddxxB oddxxC  oddxxD" in roughly the same same ratio.  And those two comparisons will have similar cos.

Comment: @Frisbee, are you sure about that comparison? Supposing the idfs are 0 for 'a', 0.5 for 'had' and 'Mary', 1 for 'little' and 'white', and 2 for 'lamb', I calculate 2.4 for "Mary had a little lamb" and 2.55 for "Mary had a white little lamb", but 1.83 for "A Mary had a little lamb". That is, the only way to decrease the norm is by increasing the frequency of the most frequent term, not by adding new words. Or are we not using the same formula?

Comment: I was thinking you normalized the document on the weighted (with IDF) not the raw frequency. That would change things.  It makes more sense to me to normalize on weighted.   Significantly changing a document || by making 'a' the most common term messes with stuff.

Comment: Sure; I just want to be sure we're working with the same formula. I think I agree with you that one will get superior results by normalizing based on raw tf * idf, that is:

$d_t=w_t(0.5+0.5\frac{w_tf(t,d)}{\mathrm{max}\{w_tf(t,d): t\in d\}})$
where $w_t=\mathrm{log}\frac{N}{|\{d\in D: t\in d\}|}$. 
(With a somewhat unclear but hopefully acceptable collision between $d$, the vector of weights $d_i$, and $d$, the document associated with that vector.) I'll have to think more tonight about whether or not this would improve the bound (but that probably involves a lot of algebra).

Answer (score 0):

I post an answer but clearly I will award the bonus to someone else

I think there is a maximum numerator if the document tf is normalized

d1⋅d2/(||d1||||d2||)

Assume d1 has same or less terms 
(or just take the d with less terms)
The maximum possible normalized tf is 1
So the maximum possible numerator sum(tf1,i * idf,i * 1 * idf,i)

||d2|| =  sum(tf1,i * idf,i * 1 * idf,i)  / ||d1|| / .6

As for a minimum I am working on that but clearly there is a minimum.
If you are going to match you are going to have ||d||